# How to check if array of object is empty?

Tags: javascript, arrays, react-native

I want to check if the array of objects is empty or not, I'm storing the result from API call in state `city_name`.

```
cities = this.state.city_name;
console.warn(cities); //this return an empty array []
cities === null ? console.log(cities) : ToastAndroid.showWithGravity('No Result 
                                                                      Found',ToastAndroid.LONG)
```

I keep getting an error `double java.lang.Double.doubleValue() on a null object`.
even tried `cities.length == 0` and `(this.state.city_name).lenght == 0` it return the same error.

This is the data from API call:

```
city_name = [{"country_flag_url": "https://b.zmtcdn.com/images/countries/flags/country_216.png", "country_id": 216, "country_name": "United States", "discovery_enabled": 1, "has_go_out_tab": 0, "has_new_ad_format": 0, "id": 11282, "is_state": 0, "name": "Del Aire, CA", "should_experiment_with": 0, "state_code": "CA", "state_id": 73, "state_name": "California"}, {"country_flag_url": "https://b.zmtcdn.com/images/countries/flags/country_216.png", "country_id": 216, "country_name": "United States", "discovery_enabled": 0, "has_go_out_tab": 0, "has_new_ad_format": 0, "id": 4463, "is_state": 0, "name": "Del Norte, CO", "should_experiment_with": 0, "state_code": "CO", "state_id": 74, "state_name": "Colorado"}, {"country_flag_url": "https://b.zmtcdn.com/images/countries/flags/country_216.png", "country_id": 216, "country_name": "United States", "discovery_enabled": 0, "has_go_out_tab": 0, "has_new_ad_format": 0, "id": 9431, "is_state": 0, "name": "Del Rio, TX", "should_experiment_with": 0, "state_code": "TX", "state_id": 111, "state_name": "Texas"}]
```

Please help me

Comment: An **empty array** is not considered to be `null`. An empty array is still an array. Don't use the ternary operator here if you're doing `console.log(cities)`, instead use a simple `if` statement to check the following: `if (cities.length === 0) { ToastAndroid.showWithGravity(...) }`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do something like this

```js
 cities = this.state.city_name;
 
 arr = cities.length;
 
 if(arr == 0) {
     console.log('no result found')
       }
 
 else {
     console.log(cities)
       }
```

Comment: It should be `length` not `lenght`.

Comment: sorry for the typo, it is length indeed

Answer (score 2):

Check for the length of the array and then try to do your task.

```
if(cities.length)
// do your task here
else
// handle here
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the issue may be that you are using === which is strict and you will get the error on a double element. Null is a string and double is a number.

```
if(cities != null && cities.length>0){
    //not empty, do something with data
}else
    //array is empty, so add values.
```

Comment: `if( cities && cities.length>0 )` to properly handle undefined too